# How to make Combobox selection fill entryboxes on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, bind

am kind of new to tkinter but i don't know what am doing wrong, i have already defined the function for attributes that would be inside the entryboxes but known are appearing after i ran the code.
that is How do I bind the select make combobox so it can autofill the relevant entry boxes from the constructed vehicle class?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox 


class Window:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Car Rental Service")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = 0
        self.var3 = 0
        self.var4 = 0
        self.var5 = 0
        self.var6 = 0
        self.var7 = 0
        self.var8 = 0

        def Vehicle(Window):
            values =str(self.cboSelectVehicleType.get())
            vtype = values
            if vtype =="Car":
                KmL.set("10")
                NumberOfDoors.set("4")
                NumberOfPassengers.set("5")
                NumberOfBeds.set("0")
                PlateNumber.set("152-C-854")
                DailyCost.set("20")
                WeeklyCost.set("95")

                n = float(DailyCost.get())
                s = float( NoofDaysRenting.get())
                price = (n*s)
                TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
                Total.set(TC)

            elif vtype =="Van":
                KmL.set("8")
                NumberOfDoors.set("3")
                NumberOfPassengers.set("3")
                NumberOfBeds.set("0")
                PlateNumber.set("142-G-511")
                DailyCost.set("45")
                WeeklyCost.set("260")

                n = float(DailyCost.get())
                s = float( NoofDaysRenting.get())
                price = (n*s)
                TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
                Total.set(TC)

            elif vtype =="Caravans":
                KmL.set("8")
                NumberOfDoors.set("0")
                NumberOfPassengers.set("0")
                NumberOfBeds.set("4")
                PlateNumber.set("131-G-111")
                DailyCost.set("50")
                WeeklyCost.set("350")

                n = float(DailyCost.get())
                s = float( NoofDaysRenting.get())
                price = (n*s)
                TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
                Total.set(TC)


          #===================================Frame==================================
        Mainframe = Frame(self.root, width =1350, height=700, bd=20, relief="raise")
        Mainframe.grid()

        LeftMainframe = Frame(Mainframe, width =1000, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        RightMainframe = Frame(Mainframe, width =350, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

        #===================================Div_Frame==================================

        LeftMainframe1 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=225, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe1.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe2 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=225, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe2.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe3 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe3.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe4 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe4.pack(side=TOP)


        RightMainframe1 = Frame(RightMainframe, width =350, height=325, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe1.pack(side=TOP)
        RightMainframe2 = Frame(RightMainframe, width =350, height=325, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

         #===================================Variable==================================
        self.var1 = IntVar()
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.var3 = IntVar()
        self.var4 = IntVar()
        self.var5 = IntVar()


        SelectVehicleType = StringVar()
        SelectMake = StringVar()
        Model = StringVar()
        KmL = StringVar()
        NumberOfDoors = StringVar()
        NumberOfPassengers = StringVar()
        NumberOfBeds = StringVar()
        PlateNumber = StringVar()
        DailyCost = StringVar()
        WeeklyCost = StringVar()
        WeekendCost = StringVar() 
        Total = StringVar()
        CustomerID = StringVar()



        def Reset():
            self.var1.set(0)
            self.var2.set(0)
            self.var3.set(0)
            self.var4.set(0)
            self.var5.set(0)
            self.var6.set(0)
            self.var7.set(0)
            self.var8.set(0)


            SelectVehicleType.set("")
            SelectMake.set("")
            Model.set("")
            KmL.set("")
            NumberOfDoors.set("")
            NumberOfPassengers.set("")
            NumberOfBeds.set("")
            PlateNumber.set("")
            DailyCost.set("")
            WeeklyCost.set("")
            WeekendCost.set("")
            Total.set("")
            CustomerID.set("")
            InvoiceID.set("")
            return Reset


        #------------------------------------LeftmainFrame2----------------------------------
        self.lblSelectVehicleType = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Select VehicleType", bd=8)
        self.lblSelectVehicleType.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.var1, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')

        self.cboSelectVehicleType.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",Vehicle)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType['value']=('','Car','Van','Caravans')
        self.cboSelectVehicleType.current(0)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.lblSelectMake = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Select Make", bd=8)
        self.lblSelectMake.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.cboSelectMake =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.var2, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')
        self.cboSelectMake['value']=('','Audi A5','Ford fiesta','Toyota Corrolla','Ford focus','Renault Clio''Renault Other','Citroen Berlingo','Peugot Partner''Renault C','Citroen B','Peugot P',)
        self.cboSelectMake.current(0)
        self.cboSelectMake.grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.lblModel = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Model", bd=8)
        self.lblModel.grid(row=0, column=4)
        self.txtModel = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtModel.grid(row=0, column=5)



        self.lblKmL = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Km/L", bd=8)
        self.lblKmL.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.txtKmL = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtKmL.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.lblNumberOfBeds = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Number Of Beds", bd=8)
        self.lblNumberOfBeds.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.txtNumberOfBeds = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtNumberOfBeds.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.lblPlateNumber = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="PlateNumber", bd=8)
        self.lblPlateNumber.grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.txtPlateNumber = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtPlateNumber.grid(row=1, column=5)

        self.lblNumberOfPassengers = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Number Of Passengers", bd=8)
        self.lblNumberOfPassengers.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.txtNumberOfPassengers = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtNumberOfPassengers.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lblDailyCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Daily Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblDailyCost.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.txtDailyCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtDailyCost.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.lblWeeklyCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Weekly Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblWeeklyCost.grid(row=2, column=4)
        self.txtWeeklyCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtWeeklyCost.grid(row=2, column=5)

        self.lblWeekendCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text=" Weekend Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblWeekendCost.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.txtWeekendCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtWeekendCost.grid(row=3, column=1)



         #----------------------------------------Leftmainframe4------------------------------
        self.btnTotal=Button(LeftMainframe4, text='Total', padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="blue", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.btnReceipt=Button(LeftMainframe4, text='Receipt', padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="green", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.btnReset=Button(LeftMainframe4, text="Reset", command=Reset, padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="blue", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=2)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    root= Tk()
    application = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why do you use bigger indentations for `Vehicle` and `Reset` ? Create normal class' methods instead of hiding them inside `__init__` - it will be more readable.

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? It gives error message. You should add this full error mesage in question (not in comment) as text (not image).

Comment: like i should create classes with vehicles with them. but i can not connect it to the application that is why i did it that way.

Comment: first problem is that you use `NoofDaysRenting.get()` but you didn't create `NoofDaysRenting = StringVar()`

Comment: i have done that now but still, entry boxes are not fill up

Comment: as i said before - did you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message? You have many other problems and I see all time new errors in terminal. Always run in terminal to see errors - it shows what is the problem.

Comment: BTW: you forgot `InvoiceID = StringVar()`

Comment: Please try to trim the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about comboboxes, we shouldn't need a couple dozen other widgets in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see another problem - you create `KML = StringVar()` but it isn't assigned to Label/Entry so it will not put text in `Label/Entry` when you use `KML.set()`. The same problem is with all other variables. Maybe better put text directly in Entry `txtKML.insert()` without using `StringVar()`

Comment: hi am getting an errorFile "<ipython-input-2-fd03db4380a8>", line 330, in Vehicle
    s = float(self.DaysRenting.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:  do you know what i might be doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two main problems

1. you forgot some `StringVar` variables - ie. `NoofDaysRenting` and `InvoiceID`
2. you forgot to use `textvariable=` to assign `StringVar` to `Entry` - ie.

   ```
    self.txtKmL = Entry(..., textvariable=self.KmL, ...)
   ```

so it doesn't update `Entry` when you update `StringVar`

---

Code after other changes.

It has `textvariable=` only in two `Entry` because there is too much work for me.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox 


class Window:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Car Rental Service")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")

        # --- Variable ---

        self.var1 = IntVar()
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.var3 = IntVar()
        self.var4 = IntVar()
        self.var5 = IntVar()
        self.var6 = IntVar()
        self.var7 = IntVar()
        self.var8 = IntVar()

        self.SelectVehicleType = StringVar()
        self.SelectMake = StringVar()
        self.Model = StringVar()
        self.KmL = StringVar()
        self.NumberOfDoors = StringVar()
        self.NumberOfPassengers = StringVar()
        self.NumberOfBeds = StringVar()
        self.PlateNumber = StringVar()
        self.DailyCost = StringVar()
        self.WeeklyCost = StringVar()
        self.WeekendCost = StringVar() 
        self.Total = StringVar()
        self.CustomerID = StringVar()

        self.NoofDaysRenting = StringVar()
        self.InvoiceID = StringVar()

        #===================================Frame==================================

        Mainframe = Frame(self.root, width =1350, height=700, bd=20, relief="raise")
        Mainframe.grid()

        LeftMainframe = Frame(Mainframe, width =1000, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        RightMainframe = Frame(Mainframe, width =350, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

        #===================================Div_Frame==================================

        LeftMainframe1 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=225, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe1.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe2 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=225, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe2.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe3 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe3.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe4 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe4.pack(side=TOP)

        RightMainframe1 = Frame(RightMainframe, width =350, height=325, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe1.pack(side=TOP)
        RightMainframe2 = Frame(RightMainframe, width =350, height=325, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        #------------------------------------LeftmainFrame2----------------------------------
        self.lblSelectVehicleType = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Select VehicleType", bd=8)
        self.lblSelectVehicleType.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.var1, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')

        self.cboSelectVehicleType.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.Vehicle)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType['value']=('','Car','Van','Caravans')
        self.cboSelectVehicleType.current(0)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.lblSelectMake = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Select Make", bd=8)
        self.lblSelectMake.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.cboSelectMake =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.var2, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')
        self.cboSelectMake['value']=('','Audi A5','Ford fiesta','Toyota Corrolla','Ford focus','Renault Clio''Renault Other','Citroen Berlingo','Peugot Partner''Renault C','Citroen B','Peugot P',)
        self.cboSelectMake.current(0)
        self.cboSelectMake.grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.lblModel = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Model", bd=8)
        self.lblModel.grid(row=0, column=4)
        self.txtModel = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtModel.grid(row=0, column=5)

        self.lblKmL = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Km/L", bd=8)
        self.lblKmL.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.txtKmL = Entry(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.KmL, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtKmL.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.lblNumberOfBeds = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Number Of Beds", bd=8)
        self.lblNumberOfBeds.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.txtNumberOfBeds = Entry(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.NumberOfBeds, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtNumberOfBeds.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.lblPlateNumber = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="PlateNumber", bd=8)
        self.lblPlateNumber.grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.txtPlateNumber = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtPlateNumber.grid(row=1, column=5)

        self.lblNumberOfPassengers = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Number Of Passengers", bd=8)
        self.lblNumberOfPassengers.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.txtNumberOfPassengers = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtNumberOfPassengers.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lblDailyCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Daily Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblDailyCost.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.txtDailyCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtDailyCost.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.lblWeeklyCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Weekly Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblWeeklyCost.grid(row=2, column=4)
        self.txtWeeklyCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtWeeklyCost.grid(row=2, column=5)

        self.lblWeekendCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text=" Weekend Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblWeekendCost.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.txtWeekendCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtWeekendCost.grid(row=3, column=1)

        #----------------------------------------Leftmainframe4------------------------------

        self.btnTotal=Button(LeftMainframe4, text='Total', padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="blue", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.btnReceipt=Button(LeftMainframe4, text='Receipt', padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="green", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.btnReset=Button(LeftMainframe4, text="Reset", command=self.Reset, padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="blue", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.Reset() # reset at start to set default values

    def Reset(self):
        self.var1.set(0)
        self.var2.set(0)
        self.var3.set(0)
        self.var4.set(0)
        self.var5.set(0)
        self.var6.set(0)
        self.var7.set(0)
        self.var8.set(0)

        self.SelectVehicleType.set("")
        self.SelectMake.set("")
        self.Model.set("")
        self.KmL.set("")
        self.NumberOfDoors.set("")
        self.NumberOfPassengers.set("")
        self.NumberOfBeds.set("")
        self.PlateNumber.set("")
        self.DailyCost.set("")
        self.WeeklyCost.set("")
        self.WeekendCost.set("")
        self.Total.set("")
        self.CustomerID.set("")
        self.InvoiceID.set("")
        self.NoofDaysRenting.set("0")
        # return Reset # makes no sense



    def Vehicle(self, event):
        #print(event)

        vtype = str(self.cboSelectVehicleType.get())

        if vtype =="Car":
            self.KmL.set("10")
            self.NumberOfDoors.set("4")
            self.NumberOfPassengers.set("5")
            self.NumberOfBeds.set("0")
            self.PlateNumber.set("152-C-854")
            self.DailyCost.set("20")
            self.WeeklyCost.set("95")

            n = float(self.DailyCost.get())
            s = float(self.NoofDaysRenting.get())
            price = (n*s)
            TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
            self.Total.set(TC)

        elif vtype =="Van":
            self.KmL.set("8")
            self.NumberOfDoors.set("3")
            self.NumberOfPassengers.set("3")
            self.NumberOfBeds.set("0")
            self.PlateNumber.set("142-G-511")
            self.DailyCost.set("45")
            self.WeeklyCost.set("260")

            n = float(self.DailyCost.get())
            s = float(self.NoofDaysRenting.get())
            price = (n*s)
            TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
            self.Total.set(TC)

        elif vtype =="Caravans":
            self.KmL.set("8")
            self.NumberOfDoors.set("0")
            self.NumberOfPassengers.set("0")
            self.NumberOfBeds.set("4")
            self.PlateNumber.set("131-G-111")
            self.DailyCost.set("50")
            self.WeeklyCost.set("350")

            n = float(self.DailyCost.get())
            s = float(self.NoofDaysRenting.get())
            price = (n*s)
            TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
            self.Total.set(TC)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    root= Tk()
    application = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @rachel so you can mark my answer as accepted. And when you will have more points of reputation you may upvote it.

Comment: please i have one question to ask, its about the Totatl(TC) i defined, after running it with the correction, i got this error File "<ipython-input-26-77cb91c70dcc>", line 331, in Vehicle
    s = float(self.DaysRenting.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:(although i changed the  NoofDaysRenting.get()) to DaysRenting.get()) in my code. so do you know why the calculation is not running

Comment: you can get the same error using `float("")` or `float("Hello World")` - so string can be empty or someone can put word instead of string with number and then it can't convert it to number. You may use `try/except` to catch it and replace with some default value - ie. `0`.

Comment: like these are some of the variables i am using: self.RentDate = StringVar()
        self.RentDueDate = StringVar()
        self.DaysRenting = StringVar()
        self.Receipt_Ref = StringVar() am trying to multiply self.DaysRenting with self.DailyCost but its response it cannot convert string to float. so shold i change the self.daysrenting to DoubleVar()

Comment: if you will write only number then you can use `DoubleVar()` but you can still get error when you put word instead of number - `DoubleVar()` will have problem to convert `Hello World` to number too. Better use `try/except`

Comment: this is the error i got:File "<ipython-input-38-5f2498800e6e>", line 331, in Vehicle
    s = float(self.DaysRenting.get())
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 529, in get
    return self._tk.getdouble(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Comment: as I said you try to convert empty string and `float("")` gives error. Use `try/except` to catch it

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes :

- use of `self.myvar` instead of `self.var1` because it has to be a StringVar, and not an IntVar
- set the variable `NoofDaysRenting` with a dummy value "22222", otherwise I had an error
- pass the argument `event` to your function `Vehicle` to bind it correctly with the combobox
- I had 2 lines to update the value of `txtWeeklyCost`, I let you do the same for all other entry boxes

And I advice you to clean your code, doing multiple classes, and not all the code in the **init** function :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox 

class Window:

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Car Rental Service")
        self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")
        self.var1 = 0
        self.var2 = 0
        self.var3 = 0
        self.var4 = 0
        self.var5 = 0
        self.var6 = 0
        self.var7 = 0
        self.var8 = 0
        self.myvar = StringVar()

        def Vehicle(event=None):
            print('self.myvar.get():', self.myvar.get())
            print('event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())

            values = self.myvar.get()
            values =str(self.cboSelectVehicleType.get())
            vtype = values
            NoofDaysRenting.set("22")
            if vtype =="Car":
                KmL.set("10")
                NumberOfDoors.set("4")
                NumberOfPassengers.set("5")
                NumberOfBeds.set("0")
                PlateNumber.set("152-C-854")
                DailyCost.set("20")
                WeeklyCost.set("95")

                n = float(DailyCost.get())
                s = float( NoofDaysRenting.get())
                price = (n*s)
                TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
                Total.set(TC)

            elif vtype =="Van":
                KmL.set("8")
                NumberOfDoors.set("3")
                NumberOfPassengers.set("3")
                NumberOfBeds.set("0")
                PlateNumber.set("142-G-511")
                DailyCost.set("45")
                WeeklyCost.set("260")

                n = float(DailyCost.get())
                s = float( NoofDaysRenting.get())
                price = (n*s)
                TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
                Total.set(TC)

            elif vtype =="Caravans":
                KmL.set("8")
                NumberOfDoors.set("0")
                NumberOfPassengers.set("0")
                NumberOfBeds.set("4")
                PlateNumber.set("131-G-111")
                DailyCost.set("50")
                WeeklyCost.set("350")

                n = float(DailyCost.get())
                s = float( NoofDaysRenting.get())
                price = (n*s)
                TC = str('%.2f'%(price))
                Total.set(TC)

            self.txtWeeklyCost.delete(0, END)
            self.txtWeeklyCost.insert(END, WeeklyCost.get())


        #===================================Frame==================================
        Mainframe = Frame(self.root, width =1350, height=700, bd=20, relief="raise")
        Mainframe.grid()

        LeftMainframe = Frame(Mainframe, width =1000, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        RightMainframe = Frame(Mainframe, width =350, height=650, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

        #===================================Div_Frame==================================

        LeftMainframe1 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=225, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe1.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe2 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=225, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe2.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe3 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe3.pack(side=TOP)
        LeftMainframe4 = Frame(LeftMainframe, width =1000, height=100, bd=8, relief="raise")
        LeftMainframe4.pack(side=TOP)


        RightMainframe1 = Frame(RightMainframe, width =350, height=325, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe1.pack(side=TOP)
        RightMainframe2 = Frame(RightMainframe, width =350, height=325, bd=8, relief="raise")
        RightMainframe2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        #===================================Variable==================================
        self.var1 = IntVar()
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.var3 = IntVar()
        self.var4 = IntVar()
        self.var5 = IntVar()


        SelectVehicleType = StringVar()
        SelectMake = StringVar()
        Model = StringVar()
        KmL = StringVar()
        NumberOfDoors = StringVar()
        NumberOfPassengers = StringVar()
        NumberOfBeds = StringVar()
        PlateNumber = StringVar()
        DailyCost = StringVar()
        WeeklyCost = StringVar()
        WeekendCost = StringVar() 
        Total = StringVar()
        CustomerID = StringVar()
        NoofDaysRenting = StringVar()



        def Reset():
            self.var1.set(0)
            self.var2.set(0)
            self.var3.set(0)
            self.var4.set(0)
            self.var5.set(0)
            self.var6.set(0)
            self.var7.set(0)
            self.var8.set(0)


            SelectVehicleType.set("")
            SelectMake.set("")
            Model.set("")
            KmL.set("")
            NumberOfDoors.set("")
            NumberOfPassengers.set("")
            NumberOfBeds.set("")
            PlateNumber.set("")
            DailyCost.set("")
            WeeklyCost.set("")
            WeekendCost.set("")
            Total.set("")
            CustomerID.set("")
            InvoiceID.set("")
            return Reset


        #------------------------------------LeftmainFrame2----------------------------------
        self.lblSelectVehicleType = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Select VehicleType", bd=8)
        self.lblSelectVehicleType.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # self.cboSelectVehicleType =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.var1, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')
        self.cboSelectVehicleType =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.myvar, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')

        self.cboSelectVehicleType.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", Vehicle)
        # self.cboSelectVehicleType.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callback)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType['value']=('','Car','Van','Caravans')
        self.cboSelectVehicleType.current(0)
        self.cboSelectVehicleType.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.lblSelectMake = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Select Make", bd=8)
        self.lblSelectMake.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.cboSelectMake =ttk.Combobox(LeftMainframe2, textvariable=self.var2, state='readonly', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),  width=25, justify='left')
        self.cboSelectMake['value']=('','Audi A5','Ford fiesta','Toyota Corrolla','Ford focus','Renault Clio''Renault Other','Citroen Berlingo','Peugot Partner''Renault C','Citroen B','Peugot P',)
        self.cboSelectMake.current(0)
        self.cboSelectMake.grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.lblModel = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Model", bd=8)
        self.lblModel.grid(row=0, column=4)
        self.txtModel = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtModel.grid(row=0, column=5)



        self.lblKmL = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Km/L", bd=8)
        self.lblKmL.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.txtKmL = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtKmL.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.lblNumberOfBeds = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Number Of Beds", bd=8)
        self.lblNumberOfBeds.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.txtNumberOfBeds = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtNumberOfBeds.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.lblPlateNumber = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="PlateNumber", bd=8)
        self.lblPlateNumber.grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.txtPlateNumber = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtPlateNumber.grid(row=1, column=5)

        self.lblNumberOfPassengers = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Number Of Passengers", bd=8)
        self.lblNumberOfPassengers.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.txtNumberOfPassengers = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtNumberOfPassengers.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lblDailyCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Daily Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblDailyCost.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.txtDailyCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtDailyCost.grid(row=2, column=3)

        self.lblWeeklyCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text="Weekly Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblWeeklyCost.grid(row=2, column=4)
        self.txtWeeklyCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtWeeklyCost.grid(row=2, column=5)

        self.lblWeekendCost = Label(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), text=" Weekend Cost", bd=8)
        self.lblWeekendCost.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.txtWeekendCost = Entry(LeftMainframe2, font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), bd=15, width=25, justify='left')
        self.txtWeekendCost.grid(row=3, column=1)



        #----------------------------------------Leftmainframe4------------------------------
        self.btnTotal=Button(LeftMainframe4, text='Total', padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="blue", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.btnReceipt=Button(LeftMainframe4, text='Receipt', padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="green", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.btnReset=Button(LeftMainframe4, text="Reset", command=Reset, padx=8, pady=8, bd=8, fg="blue", font=('arial', 13, 'bold'), width= 21, height=1,).grid(row=0, column=2)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    root= Tk()
    application = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please i have one question to ask, its about the Totatl(TC) i defined, after running it with the correction, i got this error File "<ipython-input-26-77cb91c70dcc>", line 331, in Vehicle
    s = float(self.DaysRenting.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:(although i changed the  NoofDaysRenting.get()) to DaysRenting.get()) in my code. so do you know why the calculation is not running